# the best way to make dynamic structure for strings?

Tags: c

I would like to ask how should I make absolutly dynamic strcuture of strings. Actualy I am using dynamic array with allocation of "MAX" values

Example:

```
const enum { MAX_WORDS = 20, MAX_LENGHT_OF_WORD = 50 }
...
char **words
words = ( char* ) malloc ( MAX_LENGHT_OF_WORD + 1 * sizeof( char* ));
for ( i = 0; i < MAX_WORDS; i++ ) {
    words[i] = ( char* ) malloc ( MAX_LENGHT_OF_WORD + 1 *sizeof( char* ));
}
```

Should I do it without the constats somehow? Maybe with Linked Lists?

Thank you

Comment: Don't malloc `sizeof(char *)` for `words[i]`: malloc `sizeof(char)`, which is always 1.

Comment: A linked list will be "absolutely dynamic". An array is bound by its upper bound, unless you `realloc`.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Thank you, for tips. I didn't know about realloc. I think the linked list would be the best solution for this.

Comment: Detail: `LENGHT` --> `LENGTH`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Answer (score 1):

See [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

```
words = ( char* ) malloc ( MAX_LENGHT_OF_WORD + 1 * sizeof( char* ));
                           ^^^^^ Does not seem right.
        ^^^^^^^^^ Definitely wrong since type of words is char**.
```

You can use

```
words = malloc ( MAX_WORDS * sizeof( char* ));
```

A better and more idiomatic method would be to use:

```
words = malloc ( MAX_WORDS * sizeof(*words));
```

And then...

```
for ( i = 0; i < MAX_WORDS; i++ ) {
    words[i] = ( char* ) malloc ( MAX_LENGHT_OF_WORD + 1 *sizeof( char* ));
                                                          ^^^^ Wrong
}
```

You need `sizeof(char)` there. You can use

```
    words[i] = malloc ( MAX_LENGHT_OF_WORD + 1 * sizeof(*words[i]));
```

Since `sizeof(char)` is `1`, you can simplify that to:

```
    words[i] = malloc ( MAX_LENGHT_OF_WORD + 1);
```

Comment: VS2015 doesn't let me compile " malloc ( MAX_WORDS * sizeof( char* )) " but "(char*)  malloc ( MAX_WORDS * sizeof( char* )) " seems ok. Even it is still now absolutly dynamical, it is limited by the "max" constant...

Comment: If you are compiling the file as a C++ program, then you need the explicit cast.